# Jax-Ws Custom Validation Error Response Message

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

I want to return my own custom error message which need information from the original error message at the time validate request. I use this @SchemvaValidation to custom it.

```
public class MyErrorHandler extends ValidationErrorHandler {
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingHandler.class);

public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
    logger.warn("warning", exception);
}

public static String message = "";

public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
    logger.error("error", exception);
    message += exception.getMessage();
    throw new SAXParseException("my custom" + exception.getMessage(),null);
}

public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
    logger.fatal("fatal error", exception);
    throw new SAXParseException("my custom" + exception.getMessage(),null);
}
```

}

the problem is if I throw my own message, the other error will be omit, If I don't, It will throw it own exception before my Webmethod. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

use the constructor to throw the exception. SAXParseException(String message, Locator locator, Exception e).

```
throw new SAXParseException("my custom" + exception.getMessage(),null, exception);
```

Example:

```
try {
    RuntimeException re = new RuntimeException("my runtime exception message");
    SAXException se = new SAXParseException("saxparse 1",null,re);
    SAXException se1 = new SAXParseException("saxparse 2",null,se);
    throw se1;

  } catch (SAXException e) {
      Exception e2 = e.getException();
      System.out.println(e2.getMessage());
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
```

Also I think SAXException is better suited that SAXParseException in the example.

Comment: The function  error(SAXParseException exception) is called twice, so if I throw at the first time, the later will be omit

Comment: I mean replace your throw call with the updated call.

Comment: I need to throw it at the final error, maybe the 4th or 5th.

Comment: Understand the concept of exception chaining. Whenever you throw an exception pass the original exception in the constructor. Usually all well designed exceptions will provide a constructor with such an option. So even if you throw it in 4th or 5th step, you will not loose the orignal exception. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html

Comment: The problem is I want to throw it at the final time, how can I do it?